# Spring Kinesis consumer is too slow

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-stream

The consumer running on Windows 7, Java 8.

The consumer read 1 massage in 1-5 seconds. What is the problem with my settings?

Consumer:

```
@EnableBinding({Sink.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudStreamKinesisConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudStreamKinesisConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void logger(String payload) {
        System.out.println("consumer received: " + payload);
    }
}
```

consumer application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
          consumer:
            idleBetweenPolls: 250
```

The consumer project is a  module in the same project which inherits from the following pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kinesis</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Kinesis binder ignore these settings:

[image]

I changed manually in debug time this parameter but the consumer receives 1-2 elements in 10 sec +-. What is the problem?

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/issues/44

Comment: @ArtemBilan It seems that I ask about how to use the library so maybe it's a better place to ask it.. Should I close the question there?

Comment: I already did. Try to test your solution against BUILD-SNAPSHOT. We are going to release M2 today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed a problem, @Stav Alfi.

After fixing `KinesisMessageChannelBinder` for `KinesisExtendedBindingProperties` injection, I see the proper properties population.

Therefore a config should be as like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              idleBetweenPolls: 250
```

I will push the fix soon to the mentioned issue. And hope we will release M2 today.

Thank you for your patience!

Regarding the slow consumption speed: Don't forget how fast you send message to the Kinesis stream and also keep in mind really some delay between producer and consumer. In other words there is some reasonable delay on the AWS Kinesis to make records available for consumption.

See [AWS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/faqs/) for more information:

> You can continuously add various types of data such as clickstreams, application logs, and social media to an Amazon Kinesis data stream from hundreds of thousands of sources. Within seconds, the data will be available for your Amazon Kinesis Applications to read and process from the stream.

Comment: 1. I have worked directly with `KPL` & `KCL` and I got a delay of at most `1` second. 2. I manually changed the default values inside `KinesisConsumerProperties` to be: `idleBetweenPolls = 250`,`consumerBackoff = 250` and I still see a delay of 2-3 min between the last message I pushed and the last message I received. 3. Please specify exactly how you find the problem and the solution. I want to contribute but I'm a bit lost in the source code. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I've just figured out that `KinesisExtendedBindingProperties` is not injected into the `KinesisMessageChannelBinder`. As you noticed we use an internal instance, but we have to use an injected bean. I don't have any experience with `KCL`, but everything works well for me on `kinesalite`. Would be great to get your feedback of the reason about such a big delay.

Comment: I tried now agian after you pushed and it's still not recognizing, at runtime, the `idleBetweenPolls: 250`. I tried also: `spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        idleBetweenPolls: 400` but it also didn't work.

Comment: In the `KinesisBinderProcessorTests` I have this `spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.bindings.input.consumer.idleBetweenPolls = 1` and that works well for me. I see `250` in the `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` just because the logic is there like `this.idleBetweenPolls = Math.max(250, idleBetweenPolls);`. You might not use the latest `BUILD-SNAPSHOT`. Try `-U` when you build your project.